# .htaccess to Redirect Instances of a Specific Nested Page

Tags: html, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url that contains generated strings that I need to redirect so that it sits just under the domain name. (example.. site.com/pagename.html)

I only want instances to redirect if it is nested under a page (or alternatively, if there is a way to exclude site.com/pagename.html from redirecting to itself)

So for example.. site.com/page1/pagename.html?string=stuff should 301 redirect to site.com/pagename.html and carry over the string.

However I do not want the rule to redirect any just instance if "pagename.html" as I need to prevent it from looping. Also I can not reference /page1/ in this example as there are thousands of instances of different parent pages so I believe I need to use a wildcard or regular expression to make this work.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated as I barely know html.

So far I have tested this and it carries over the string that follows the page name succcesfully. But now I need to replace "test" with "pagename" and either make an exclusion or create a condition..

```
# Rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# 301 Redirect 1
RewriteRule ^test\.html$ /pagename.html [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: Did you try something like `RewriteRule ^/?page\d+/(.*)$ /pagename.html [R=301,NE,NC,L]`? It should replace `/page{NUMBER}/any_page.html` to `/pagename.html`.

Comment: Hmm. This is essentially what I updated the code with:

    # Needed before any rewriting
    RewriteEngine On

    ## 301 Redirects
    # 301 Redirect 1
    RewriteRule ^/?page\d+/(.*)$ /page.html [R=301,NE,NC,L]

Not sure if I implemented it incorrectly or not, but there was no change.

Comment: @stribizhev I also just tried adding this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pagename.html$ - [L]

above my original code based on a different thread I saw to exclude specific pages, but stil no luck either.

Comment: rather than post your update as a comment, please get comforatable with editing your question. I recommend adding a section at the end labeled with **edit**. Good luck.